# Shell Script to remove double quotes within the column value

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk, grep

I have a input text file with 10 columns, while processing this file, in one of the middle column, I am getting this type of data.I required column value to be as below:

Input Column value: "This is my new program:"Hello World""

Required Column value: "This is my new program: Hello World".

Please help me in any Unix shell scripts or any commands.
Really appreciate your time and thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a full input, exactly as is? it's hard to derive a solution based on partial data. Otherwise, a simple sed 's/"//g' would suffice.

Comment: Do you have any control about how the input file is generated? Sounds like it's generating invalid CSV. You should have `"This is my new program:""Hello World"""`

Comment: No, I don't have any control over source file. I just need to have only first and last double quotes..All the extra double quotes in between the column value need to be removed.

Comment: What is the column separator?

Comment: Pipe (|) delimiter

Comment: Remove other double quotes in each colum data except the boundaries of text strings 

Example:
Column separator is pipe(|)

"Hi"| "California"|"eating apple "very nice" very big"|

I want above record as:

 "Hi"| "California"|"eating apple very nice very big"|

Answer (score 30):

A very simple option is to use sed as @Dani proposes if you want to remove all double-quotes.

```
$ echo "This is my program \"Hello World\"" | sed 's/"//g'

This is my program Hello World
```

Nevertheless, if you want to remove only internal quotes, I would suggest removing all quotes and adding one at the beginning and one at the end as follows.

Let's say we have a file sample.txt with these contents:

```
$ cat sample.txt

"This is the "First" Line"
"This is the "Second" Line"
"This is the "Third" Line"
```

Then, if you want to remove only internal quotes, I would suggest the following:

```
$ cat sample.txt | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/^/"/' |sed 's/$/"/'

"This is the First Line"
"This is the Second Line"
"This is the Third Line"
```

Explanation:

**sed 's/"//g'** removes all double quotes on each line

**sed 's/^/"/'** adds a double-quote at the beginning of each line

**sed 's/$/"/'** adds a double-quote at the end of each line

**sed 's/|/"|"/g'** adds a quote before and after each pipe.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: As per the pipe separator comment, we have to slightly change the command

Let sample.txt be:

```
$ cat sample.txt

"This is the "First" column"|"This is the "Second" column"|"This is the "Third" column"
```

Then, adding a replacer command for the pipe give us the final solution.

```
$ cat sample.txt | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/^/"/' |sed 's/$/"/' | sed 's/|/"|"/g'

"This is the First column"|"This is the Second column"|"This is the Third column"
```

### The script option

Using this sample.txt file

```
$ cat sample.txt
"This is the "first" column"|12345|"This is the "second" column"|67890|"This is the "third" column"
```

And this script

```
#!/bin/ksh

counter=1
column="initialized"
result=""
while [[ "$column" != "" ]]
do
    eval "column=$(cat sample.txt | cut -d"|" -f$counter)"
    eval "text=$(cat sample.txt | cut -d"|" -f$counter | grep '"')"
    if [[ "$column" = "$text" && -n "$column" ]]
    then
        if [[ "$result" = "" ]]
        then
            result="_2quotehere_${column}_2quotehere_"
        else
            result="${result}|_2quotehere_${column}_2quotehere_"
        fi
    else
        if [[ -n "$column" ]]
        then
            if [[ "$result" = "" ]]
            then
                result="${column}"
            else
                result="${result}|${column}"
            fi
        fi
    fi
    echo $result | sed 's/_2quotehere_/"/g' > output.txt
    (( counter+=1 ))
done
cat output.txt
exit 0
```

You will get this:

```
$ ./process.sh
"This is the first column"|12345|"This is the second column"|67890|"This is the third column"

$ cat output.txt
"This is the first column"|12345|"This is the second column"|67890|"This is the third column"
```

I hope this is the processing you need.

Let me know!

#### FINAL EDIT

This script processes the input line you provided, several times included. Only restriction is that all 20 columns MUST BE on the same line.

```
#!/bin/ksh

rm output.txt > /dev/null 2>&1
column="initialized"
result=""
lineCounter=1
while read line
do
    print "LINE $lineCounter: $line"
    counter=1
    while [[ ${counter} -le 20 ]]
    do
        eval 'column=$(print ${line} | cut -d"|" -f$counter)'
        eval 'text=$(print ${line} | cut -d"|" -f$counter | grep \")'
        print "LINE ${lineCounter} COLUMN ${counter}: $column"
        if [[ "$column" = "$text" && -n ${column} ]]
        then
            if [[ "$result" = "" ]]
            then
                result="_2quotehere_$(echo ${column} | sed 's/\"//g')_2quotehere_"
            else
                result="${result}|_2quotehere_$( echo ${column} | sed 's/\"//g')_2quotehere_"
            fi
        else
            if [[ "$result" = "" ]]
            then
                result=${column}
            else
                result="${result}|${column}"
            fi
        fi
        (( counter+=1 ))
    done
    (( lineCounter+=1 ))
    echo -e $result | sed 's/_2quotehere_/"/g' >> output.txt
    result=""
done < input.txt
print "OUTPUT CONTENTS:"
cat output.txt

exit 0
```

From here, you must be able to get it working for your particular case.

Comment: `sed 's/\([^"]\)"/\1/g'`

Comment: But here is the problem.. In my row i have numeric columns also..If i go with this, sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/^/"/' |sed 's/$/"/' | sed 's/|/"|"/g'  . This will print all column values with double quotes but I just want only string columns to have double quotes. How to write this cat sample.txt | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/^/"/' |sed 's/$/"/' | sed 's/|/"|"/g' into a text file?

Comment: To dump it into a text file, just redirect the output

cat sample.txt | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/^/"/' |sed 's/$/"/' | sed 's/|/"|"/g' > output.txt

Let me look for a workaround for the numbers.

Is there any other piece of information we need to solve this?

Comment: By the complexity of the problem, I think is better to go for an structured script that makes it happen. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes i agree.. we need to go by scripting.. Any inputs because i am very basic level in scripting.. Thanks a lot for your time..

Comment: I'd go like this: (1) Split the fields.  (2) Check and convert if it's a text field.  (3) Concatenate again.  (4) Dump to output file.

Comment: I'm quite busy right now, but in a couple hours I can get you some working example.

Comment: Ok sure thank you.I will modify based on your example

Comment: Hi Jesus,  One more thing i want to let you know that i have some input records as below: "123455"|456782|"2014-12-12"|"eating apple "very nice very big""|.  Here we want the record to be as "123455"|456782|"2014-12-12"|"eating apple very nice very big"|..What this means, only in specific columns we need to remove the extra double quotes..Because i don't want remove the quotes in date columns, some string column("123455" is string given by source team) as shown in example record here.

Comment: OK, give a try to the script I posted! It should work.

Comment: Hi Jesus, I tried the code you sent..But still need more..Here is what happened. I have more than 100K records in my source file. sample row: 123|145672|456237|"2012-04-02"|"2015-09-30"|"Hello:"myworld""|"abc"|"2010-05-15"|"def"|||||"abcd@gmail.com"||||.. When i use the code you posted, it is processing just first record only and that too partially. 123|145672|456237|"2012-04-02"|"2015-09-30"|"Hello:"myworld""|"abc"|"2010-05-15"|"def" ... It processed till "def" .Just one row is picked and that too partially. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, I see you have empty fields there... "def"|||||"abcd@gmail.com".  Man, that's why I asked about any other requirements. The stop condition is a blank (or null) string. Just change the stop condition and edit it so that it adds new lines too. This is why you need to be VERY specific when asking for code. In about 3 hours, I can work on it when I get home. So I guess you should try to correct the code in the mean time.

Comment: Ok sure, I will try to modify the code before you post the new code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Jesus,I tried with removing the exit code.. But still it is not picking from second record and also empty null values.. Could you help me. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I will give it a shot during the afternoon today. (0:06am at the moment, so I need to get some rest)

Comment: OK, working on it... Will update in a while.

Comment: Karthik, question. Is the number of columns fixed?

Comment: Yes, total columns number is fixed(20 columns). For some rows there will be also carriage return values.I mean example like comment text column value will be continued to next line.

Comment: And those CR must be kept intact? Please put here the more complex row you may think of

Comment: 1345|19998|56725|"2007-04-02"|"2003-09-30"|"abc gggg"|"abc"|"2012-01-01"|"false"|"2113-10-09"|||"2099-09-28"||"2193-10-03"|"abc@gmail.COM"|"2012-12-18"|"def@gmail.COM"|"2009-10-09"|"we are doing unit testing.  "find all the bugs before move to next deployment.

Complete the unit testing by EOD"."

Comment: Hi Jesus, Did you get any time today to help in fixing my unix script code. Thanks!

Comment: I've been quite busy, and will be during this week, but will try to get a chance to fix it.

Comment: @Karthik: Please stop having this conversation in comments.  You should [edit your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/236154/edit) to show examples of your data, what commands you've tried, what results they give, and why they aren't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest criteria to edit a field is "if it has letters".
Fields with only numbers (and some symbols .,- etc.) should be left alone.
This simple awk script does the job:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -v FS='|' -v OFS='|' '{
for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    if ( $i ~ /[a-zA-Z]/ ) {
        gsub(/["]/,"",$i); $i="\"" $i "\""    # Remove dquotes, add them back.
    }
} }1' input.txt >output.txt
```